# configure jta transaction manager using spring?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, java-ee-7

I have below configuration in my spring config file. I am using Spring3, Hibernate4 and Tomcat7.

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="wcDataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/UserTransaction" resource-ref="false" environment-ref="remoteEnv" />

    <util:properties id="remoteEnv">
        <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://jndi.myURL.me:1099</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
        <prop key="jnp.disableDiscovery">true</prop>
    </util:properties>

   <bean id="dataSourceKS" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${password}" />
        <!-- pool sizing -->
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="15" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="6000" />
        <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection" value="300" />

    </bean>

    <bean name="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceKS"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.sample.MyBean</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now how can i configure `JTATransactionManager` here to use @Transactional? Here i have `wcDataSource` and `dataSourceKS`. Thanks!

Thanks!

Comment: JTA is tricky, at best, to get working, especially when working with remote resources. Your datasource should also be a remote lookup, probably from the same server, it should be at least XA capable and should/must be known to the underlying JTA tx implementation. Next you would also need to configure hibernate appropriatly (for starters instead of `datasource` set `jtaDataSource` on the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`).

Comment: You should take a look at this [link](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-jta-multiple-resource-transactions-in-tomcat-with-atomikos-example), that is what are trying to do.

(Atomikos being their own implementation of a jta manager, but spring configuration will be the same)

Comment: Arnaud, Please provide the link...

Comment: Arnaud, i need to provide a connection to AtomikosDataSourceBean through jndi look up. Could you please provide some idea?

Answer (score 4):

The **[JtaTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-strategies)** does not need to know about the DataSource, or any other specific resources, because it uses the container’s global transaction management infrastructure.
So conf file should look like this

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://lafernando.com/2011/01/05/xa-transactions-with-apache-dbcp/ which does it in code but which you should be able to translate to a spring configuration.

Which would result in something like this.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="userTransaction" jndi-name="java:comp/UserTransaction" resource-ref="false" environment-ref="remoteEnv" />
<jee:jndi-lookup id="jtaTransactionManager" jndi-name="java:comp/TransactionManager" resource-ref="false" environment-ref="remoteEnv" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="userTransaction"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="jtaTransactionManager"/>
</bean>

<util:properties id="remoteEnv">
    <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://jndi.myURL.me:1099</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
    <prop key="jnp.disableDiscovery">true</prop>
</util:properties>

<bean id="oracleXaDataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource">
    <property name="user" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
    <property name="url" value="${url}" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceKS" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.managed.BasicManagedDatasource">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jtaTransactionManager" />
    <property name="xaDataSourceInstance" ref="oracleXaDataSource" />
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="15" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="6000" />
    <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection" value="300" />
</bean>

<bean name="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="dataSourceKS"/>
    // .. other hibernate properties
</bean>
```

Note the change to commons-dbcp as c3p0 doesn't have XA capable implementations.

Comment: The link is dead